# How to insert into mysql table based on select results

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I am working on a migration into wordpress and would like to update some post tags via MySQL as it would be more elegant than creating a PHP script.

I am looking to do a basic insert into a table for all results in a select statement:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
VALUES  
    (SELECT wp_posts.ID as topicID
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE post_parent = 51521),'28','0';
```

This throws an error:

> Error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

I assume its expecting just one result, however I want to do the insert for all 50+ records returned in the select.

I tried to do the select first but with no joy.

If I cannot find the SQL solution I will have to create a migration script but it seems overkill for such a simple command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT wp_posts.ID, '28','0'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = 51521
```